# how to change the favicon in an abp webassembly project?

Tags: webassembly, favicon, abp

I want to change the favicon in the httpapi.host project in an abp wasm solution. In the Blazor Project it was easy....

I tried to add a favicon.svg in the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the favicon of your Blazor application, you should replace the `favicon.ico` file under the **wwwroot** folder of your Blazor application.

[image]

After you changed the file, you should see the favicon is changed without re-running the application.

Comment: @jxmmlx You can check the following links if you are using LeptonX Theme: https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/4270/Changing-the-favicon https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/3698/LeptonX-MVC---How-to-change-the-logo

Comment: HttpApi.Host project is also an MVC project, so the required changes are the same.

Comment: @jxmmlx you need to create it yourself, the images folder is in the theme module. When you create a new image and put it into the images folder, it will replace the related favicon.